# VB.Net Loop freezes program

Tags: vb.net, while-loop

I have a loop that increases a a progress bar value every second. It works fine, but if you click anywhere in the form, the window turns white and it says "YOURTITLEHERE (No response)".
Here is the loop code:

```
Private Sub incprogress()
    While ProgressBar1.Value < 1000
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't block the UI thread.

Comment: @SLaks I'm new to VB.Net, so I don't know what you mean. Would you mind to write a example code?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728192/updating-a-progress-bar-in-a-c-sharp-gui-from-another-thread-and-class

Comment: @HanletEscaño That's not VB.Net

Comment: @FritzF, I know, it should just give you an idea of what to do, how to proceed. Most likely you will not find a direct answer to your problem, but the fact is that the question has been answered in c#.

Comment: Why are you doing this?...exactly what are you "tracking" progress of?

Comment: your program is working *exactly* as coded

Comment: If you have an operation that will take an unknown amount of time to complete (or a percentage complete cannot be obtained or computed) then use the Marquee style: `ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee`.  See [ProgressBarStyle Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information: _Marquee - Indicates progress by continuously scrolling a block across a ProgressBar in a marquee fashion._

Answer (score 4):

Better yet, use a timer that ticks once per second. It's best not to play with Threads if you don't know what you are doing.

If you look in your toolbox, you'll find a Timer control that you can drag onto your form.
Set its interval to 1000, Enable it, and handle its Tick event to have something happen once per second.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something more complicated than sleep between progress bar updates (like process lines in a file or wait for network traffic) you might use the BackgroundWorker instead of Timer.  It is a little more complex to set up, but it will let you do all the heavy lifting off of your GUI thread so the GUI remains responsive.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim bgw As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        bgw = New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        AddHandler bgw.DoWork, AddressOf bgw_DoWork
        AddHandler bgw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bgw_ProgressChanged
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
        While ProgressBar1.Value < 1000
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) 'Optionally do some useful work here off the UI thread
            bgw.ReportProgress(0) 'optionally report a real percentage done
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        If ProgressBar1.Value < 1000 Then
            ProgressBar1.Value += 1 'optionally set progress bar to real percentage done
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```